# Visual Studio's profiling API

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

I can't properly setup manual profiling using Visual Studio's API. I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985641.aspx) MSDN guide to link their lib to my project. But I'm getting `unresolved external symbol __imp_StopProfile` while trying to launch the code that includes and uses `StopProfile` function. I've set the path to the profiling library in my project properties and added the name of the library to the linker. I tried to include both VS12 and VS14 versions, no luck.

Comment: The proper name is `__imp_StopProfile@8`.  You, somehow, got the compiler to assume that it is a `__cdecl` function instead of `__stdcall`  Maybe you have a macro that mangles the declaration in the VSPerf.h #include file and stomps `_stdcall`.  Hard to guess from the question..

Comment: @HansPassant I tried to redefine `__stdcall` but it didn't help, what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to build x64 application which requires x64 VSPerf.lib which can be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64\PerfSDK`. Please note that `x64` folder there.